# How to create a condition on only one classical bit when we have a total of 2 classic bits in the system

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, qiskit, circuit-construction

I am trying to make a quantum circuit with one qubit and 2 classical bits for each measurment in the system below: 
[image: condition on the first measurment]

I want to make condition on the first bit: if the first collapse to zero so x operator is act on the circuit, else (one) nothing is acting on the circuit.

I am using qiskit language.

but when I try to create my circuit, there is always an error:

```
#definitions
q = QuantumRegister(1)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

# building the circuit
qc.h(q)
qc.measure(q[0],c[0])
qc.x(q[0]).c[0]_if(c[0], 0)
qc.measure(q[0],c[1])
circuit_drawer(qc)
```

and the error is:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-66c70285946b>", line 3
    qc.x(q[0]).c[0]_if(c[0], 0)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how to write it correctly?

When I try to change

```
qc.x(q[0]).c[0]_if(c[0], 0)
```

with:

```
qc.x(q).c_if(c, 0)
```

I succeed in building my circuit but I get circuit that I don`t want to work with:
[image: Unwanted condition on measurment]

I wish for help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [controlled NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) gate does the opposite of what you want, it applies $X$ to the target qubit if the control qubit is 1, and does nothing if the control qubit is 0.

What you want is to apply $X$ when the control qubit is 0 and do nothing when it is 1. This can be accomplished by applying a NOT gate (i.e. an $X$ gate) before doing the CNOT.

In the IBM composer it would look like this:

[image]

The code for doing CNOT in quiskit is:

```
gate cx c,t {
 CX c,t; 
}
```

Since there is a specific gate for what you want to do, you do not need any "if statements"!

Comment: Do I need to put this algorithm between 2 measurments?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. One thing I can say though, is that you second measurement should just read 0.

Comment: i want to sand inital state |00> to |01> 
and |10> to |10> 
the second space in the initial function is always 0 because the first measurment is on the first classical bit

Comment: If that is all ou want to do, the circuit I gave you in my answer is enough. You don't need anything else.

Comment: so the circuit will be:
q[0]____[H]___[meas]______[+]_______________
q[1]________________[x]___( )____[meas]______

c[0]____________V_________________________
c[1]_____________________________V________ ?????

Comment: It depends what you want to do brother. I have you the circuit for |00> to |01> and |10> to |10>. I don't know what your over goal is.

Comment: @DanielVainshtein: Considering how many follow-up questions you've asked, and the amount of effort put into the answer, it might be a good idea to show some appreciation when people invest their time to helping you :)

Answer (score 3):

See the answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/how-would-one-implement-a-quantum-equivalent-of-a-while-loop-in-ibm-qiskit) for more on how the classical control works. Basically, your operations are controlled on the integer stored (in binary) across a register rather than on the individual bits themselves.

I also don't quite know the 'best practice' way of controlling on single bits, but I can tell you my workaround. Instead of creating a register with two bits, I create a list of two single qubit registers.

```
c = [ ClassicalRegister(1) for _ in range(2) ]
```

These can be added using the `add` method of a quantum circuit.

```
q = QuantumRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q)
for register in c:
    qc.add_register( register )
```

Then it is possible to use your 'building the circuit' code can be done with

```
qc.h(q)
qc.measure(q,c[0])
qc.x(q[0]).c_if(c[0], 0)
qc.measure(q,c[1])
circuit_drawer(qc)
```

This works because `c[0]` now refers to a classical register, rather than a single bit from a classical register.

Comment: I think at some point the API changed, but in any case the method is now called `add_register` not just `add`.